# Getting error while configuring Union All transformation in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, union-all

I am doing one exercise from Microsoft Training Kit (70-463) in which I have to create one SSIS package which takes data from 3 different tables and merge into one DW table in between there are various transformation I have to perform. While creating transformation I am stuck at the `Union All` transformation which takes data from `Look Up` and `Derived Column` transformation. I am getting below error while I am configuring `Union All` transformation.

[image]

For more information you can refer to this
[exercise document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2WSqlnDDmo1RnBkWVFIWDlzRFE)

I am having trouble at Exe 2 step number 10

Comment: That particular error usually indicates that the data types of the columns you are trying to union are not the same. Have a look at the Gender column of the tables involved, and if at all possible, post the create script of the tables and the source queries that go into the Union All.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the data type of gender in source table. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the exercises, the issue is due to the two `Gender` columns being fed into the `Union All` component are not the same.

In the dbo.Customers table from exercise 1, the column is defined as nchar(1), while the `derived column` component in exercise 2 adds a value `N/A` (which is 3 characters).

One possible solution would be to specifically cast the Gender column coming out of dbo.Customers as an nvarchar(3) column. Another workaround could be to replaced "N/A" with a questionmark in the Derived Column component.

Comment: For that I was getting truncate warning at the destination adapter. The issue with gender data type of source table. It was `nvarchar`. I changed it to `nchar`. Now, It's working.

Comment: @Jay Is the table created in step 1 the destination? I didn't fully follow the exercise, so I might have missed something. In any case, glad to hear you got it resolved.

Comment: Yes. It was destination table.